# ipad background image should be 1024*748 or 2048*1536?

Tags: ios, ipad

In my app, I need to set background image for a fullscreen UIView in iPad. I can't figure out that whether I should use 1024*768 or 2048*1536 for image size.

Comment: How is this about programming?

Comment: You can set the simulator to Retina mode, too.

Comment: @Thilo yes,I will try it.

Comment: whoops.....  why vote down my question.I am feeling sad.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but it's apparent that this question is profoundly misconceived.  You're asking us if it's ok to make a 1024x768 image? How to get a developer's id?  Or what?

Comment: @GarryVass Sorry about that.I have editted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for non retina it should be 1024X768 with image name as "name_of_image_here.png"

for retina device it should be 2048X1536 with image name as "name_of_image_here@2x.png"

Comment: Thank you,the `1024X278` should be `1024X748` with image name as "name_of_image_here.png".Maybe a small spell mistake,:)